# Binding to dependency property

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a simple custom user control:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I use it in MainPage.xaml as follows:

```
<local:WindowsPhoneControl1 x:Name="customControl" DisplayText="test">

</local:WindowsPhoneControl1>
```

If in MainPage.xaml.cs I do:

```
PersonName = "George";
customControl.DataContext = this;
```

Then *George* is displayed, but *test* isn't. This makes sense, but I don't know how to bind to the DisplayText property.

Of course, the following won't work, since *George* won't be displayed:

```
customControl.DataContext = customControl;
```

Please note that this should work for WP/silverlight development, so stuff like AncestorType may not be available (not that it would necessarily be useful)

Comment: You should read this article on dependency properties value precedence: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Answer (score 1):

There's probably more than one way to do this.  Here's one: add a Dependency Property to your User Control for `PersonName`, and a regular property for `DisplayText` (no DP needed since you're not binding to it).

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("PersonName", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), null);

public string DisplayText { get; set; }
public string PersonName
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(PersonNameProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PersonNameProperty, value); }
}
```

Then, set the User Control's `DataContext` to be `LayoutRoot` (after initializing in the constructor).

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

---

**Edit** The following way may be easier (definitely it's more direct), but requires Silverlight 5.  You can bind to the property `DisplayText` by using it using [`RelativeSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.relativesource.ancestortype%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                              Path=DisplayText}"/>
```

So here the DataContext of the user control can still be set to `MainPage`, and the data source for this one element can be pointed to the User Control's code-behind class.

Comment: Adding the PersonName dependency property forces me to write something like PersonName="{Binding PersonName}" right? I wish I could use your other solution, but unfortunately I cannot use AncestorType (as explained)

Comment: @uWat `AncestorType` should work for the later versions of Silverlight ... if not, I wonder if you could use `ElementName` instead.  Checking...

Comment: @uWat hm, well, AncestorType is supported in Silverlight, but only version 5.  And `ElementName` doesn't seem to work.  But yeah, the dependency property approach requires `{Binding PersonName}`.